# SQL to find date larger than another

Tags: sql, datetime, db2

I am trying to run a query on a DB2 database that is included in an INNER JOIN that will show everything that is older than 1 year. 
Here is the code I am running:

```
month(T4.BIRTH_DT) > (SELECT CURRENT DATE - (DAY(CURRENT DATE) DAYS) - 11 MONTH + 1 DAY from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 )
```

But I get the following error:

> SQL0401N  The data types of the operands for the operation ">" are not compatible.  SQLSTATE=42818

To me it looks like both should be dates but I cannot for the life of me figure out what the format should be.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You don't need to reference the dummy table. Just use the date expression by itself. I don't remember much DB2 but you might still get that to work using `> ALL (select ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a simpler version:

```
T4.BIRTH_DT < CURRENT DATE - 1 YEARS
```

Comment: Simplified answer (thank you Gordon)

month(T4.Birth_DT) = (MONTH(CURRENT DATE - 11 MONTHS))

Dawned on me that I was looking only for the month in the first part and the whole date in the second, once I told it to only look for the month it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified answer

month(T4.Birth_DT) = (MONTH(CURRENT DATE - 11 MONTHS))